# Token id to be passed from one API to another API using CURL PHP

Tags: php, php-curl

I have a client API where the first API is `loginAPI` URL when it triggers the token ID will be generated and it will be activated only for 20mins, and the token ID has to pass in the main API URL has in headers. After 20mins the `loginAPI` Url has to trigger once again to get the fresh token id every time.

So I am new this kind of issue so can anyone help me giving ideas/suggestions to run the API.

Comment: you can achieve by setting cron from cpanel, see this link for more help https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-cron-jobs-with-php--net-19428

Comment: formatting and other improvements

Answer (score 0):

@Ritesh :  Please follow below steps

1. Create on device table in your system in that table you manage your user id and device id and token id, token time.
2. When you call main api  then token time is get update with respective of that token id
3. Match current time and token updated time. If time interval is greater than  20 minute then update token id

   ```
   function checkValidSession($userToken)
   {
         if(trim($userToken)=="")
         {
              $array = array('error_code' => 301, 'message' => 'Token is missing','status'=>FAIL);
              return $array;
         }else
         {
              $CI = & get_instance();
              $result = $CI->db->select("*")->from('tbl_devices')->where("token",$userToken)->get()->row();

              if(!$result)
              {
                   $array = array('error_code' => 302, 'message' => 'Invalid token','status'=>FAIL);
                   return $array;
               }
              else
              {
                   $updated_date = $result->updated_date;
                   $tokenTime = strtotime($updated_date);
                   $currTime = time();
                   $minutes =  round(abs($currTime - $tokenTime) / 60,2);
                   if($minutes>20)
                   {
                        Run login webservice again

                   }
                   else
                   {
                        $CI->db->update('tbl_devices',array('updated_date'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s')),array('token'=>$userToken));
                        $array = array('error_code' => 0,'data'=>$result,'message' => 'Valid token','status'=>SUCCESS);
                        return $array;
                   }
              }
         }
    }
   ```

Following are table schema 
http://prntscr.com/khz8wz

Comment: Hi Abhijit, any sample code will help me to understand better.

Comment: in the above code shows the CI framework but can it be any core php. I am not familiar in the CI framework